# Cloth falls inside object rather than on top

Tags: cloth-simulation, collision

As you can see in the picture, the blanket folds inside of the top mattress when it's supposed to fall on top. The blanket starts outside of the perimeter of the mattress but gets sucked in for some reason

This is using Blender 2.8 and the cloth and collision modifiers have not been changed from default settings.[image]

Comment: You need to provide substantially more information for us to reproduce your error and to help answer your question.

Comment: increase outer thickness to at least 0.2 and try again

Comment: First thing, check your normals.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to untick *Single Sided* in the *Softbody and Cloth* menu of the mattress collision.

Answer (score 0):

In *Collision* tab, *Softbody and Cloth* menu, check *Override Normals*, than the sheet will stay on the top. (Moreover, when you uncheck the *Override Normals* again, the sheet will stay on the top.)